# Download videos in the supplementary information section on nature.com

Tags: journals, online-resource, supporting-information

I'm wondering how can I download the videos in the supplementary information section on nature.com ([here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93915-0#Sec9)).
My professor adds them in the slides so I know that is possible to do it, but it's a bit tricky.

I tried from the developer tools of chrome and firefox, but no way, in the media section there isn't a link to the video I'm playing.

Comment: It seems they're streaming video rather than directly embedding it. This is why there are transport stream (.ts) files showing in the developer tools rather than a more conventional media format. I suspect you can make something work using the information in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22188332/7492468).

Answer (score 1):

On [their support website](https://support.nature.com/en/support/solutions/articles/6000210902-supplementary-information), it says that you may need a subscription to the journal to be able to download the supplementary information, so that might be the issue.

They also state that you can contact them in case you can't access the data (an email adress is provided). So you might want to give this a try.

Comment: Does anyone have a subscription to Scientific Reports? As far as I know, it's an entirely open access journal. I don't think the question is about "accessing the data", which seem to be freely available, rather it's about being able to save the videos to disk like you can do with the supplemental PDF.

Comment: Hello @Anyon yes that's the point.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi But the encourage you to inquire with them per email if you can't access any of the materials, so I suggest you try that.

Comment: Hello @Sursula thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering how can I download the videos in the supplementary information section on nature.com ([here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93915-0#Sec9)).

This varies. I'm not sure if it is mainly a function of journal and video file format, or if licensing is also a factor, but different articles require different approaches. For many papers, it's as easy as right-clicking on a link and saving as file ([example](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-37259-5#Sec21)). In other cases, there is an option in the top right of the player to download the video, as in [this example](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-023-32106-5#Sec26):

[image: Frame from Supplementary Video 1 of "Design of topology optimized compliant legs for bio-inspired quadruped robots"]

However, the [article you linked to](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93915-0#Sec9) is a tougher nut to crack. If you don't want to contact the journal or authors, or tried unsuccessfully, there are still solutions. Using the Inspect functionality in Chrome or Firefox, looking under the Network tab as a video starts to play, one finds the file extensions .m3u8 and .ts, indicating the video is streamed in the [MPEG Transport Stream format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream). There is typically a master .m3u8 file containing the metadata for the .ts files, including their URLS. As outlined in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22188332/7492468), there are a number of approaches to download such videos. Some selected options are

1. A very user friendly approach is the [Video DownloadHelper](https://www.downloadhelper.net/) extension for Firefox or Chrome. In order to actually download the video to disk, one is required to install a companion app, which is open sourced. Personally, I'm happy to install and run it in a (Linux) virtual machine, but obviously you'll have to make your own choices about what software to trust. In any case, I found this solution works well, including when the video is provided in multiple resolutions.
2. [Another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335818/7492468) where you might not need to install any new software is to use functionality built into VLC Media Player. Find the `master.m3u8` file using your browser's dev tools and copy the URL. In VLC, choose Media -> Convert/Save -> Network, paste the URL and proceed to download it. This seems to work well when the video is provided in a single resolution listed in the .m3u8 (and there is a single `chunklist*.m3u8` file shown in the browser dev tools), but not as well when there are multiple resolutions / chunklists.
3. The nearly manual approach. From the Inspect pane in the browser, simply save all the .m3u8 and .ts files manually. (At least for the videos in the article you linked this is manageable.) Then edit the `master.m3u8` file to only reference the chunklist you desire, removing the others. Now you can open the master file locally using VLC and convert it as above. Alternatively, it should be possible to combine the .ts files using ffmpeg.

In principle, it is also possible to use various terminal tools like ffmpeg to download the videos directly using only the .m3u8 links, but I encountered a lot of 403 Forbidden Errors doing so and gave up trying.

Comment: Another tool would be yt-dlp. It may be able to handle the page directly, otherwise it should be able to download from the master.m3u8 link. And if they don't support nature yet they may even be interested in adding support for it.

Comment: @allo I did try youtube-dl but ran into 403 errors. I didn't try later forks like yt-dlp. For now, anyway, their [list of supported sites](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/master/supportedsites.md) does not seem to include nature.com.

Comment: Try the m3u8 URL, try changing the useragent, and when it still does not work try asking StackOverflow ;)